# Adding PDF reader to Blackberry Playbook app

Tags: url, pdf, blackberry-playbook

I need to add a PDF reader that reads a PDF document from a URL to my Blackberry Playbook app. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PlayBook will come with Adobe Reader, so you shouldn't have to add anything else.

In principle, using [QNXApplication.qnxApplication.openFile('myfile.pdf')](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/airapi/1.0.0/qnx/system/QNXApplication.html#openFile%28%29) should be sufficient to open that file in Reader.

None of this has been documented yet by RIM so you will have to wait at least until the release of the 1.0 SDK (expected prior to the tablet shipping, but maybe not by much) to learn more.

Comment: thanks that is answering my question in that way; simulator has no adobe reader so i cannot open pdf files, but play book will have.

Comment: @Merve, it's even possible that the 1.0 SDK (apparently to be available just before launch) may even have some of the extra apps in it, like Reader.  They haven't said, though I think it's been implied.  Should know soon!

Comment: since the new SDK has released, is there any way for showing PDF on the application itself.

Comment: @Anil, no, as of yet there's no way.  It may become possible once the native SDK is available.  It's expected to be in open beta form next week.

Comment: can we use any library like http://code.google.com/p/trapeze-reader/ for the same.

Comment: @Anil, any AS3 library that doesn't depend on native extensions probably has a good chance of working.